# Is there a focus changed event in urwid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, urwid

Is it possible to track the change of the highlighted item in an `urwid.ListBox` object? Or even via a `ListWalker` object?

I would like to call a callback when the user moves from one item to another using the arrow keys `[]`, `[]`, *not* when the user hits `[Enter]` on one item.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some research and experimentation, it's possible to do this by registering the `modified` signal with the `ListWalker` object.

```
import urwid

def callback():
    index = str(listBox.get_focus()[1])
    debug.set_text("Index of selected item: " + index)


debug = urwid.Text("Debug")

captions = "A B C D E F".split()
items = [urwid.Button(caption) for caption in captions]
walker = urwid.SimpleListWalker(items)
listBox = urwid.ListBox(walker)

urwid.connect_signal(walker, "modified", callback)

frame = urwid.Frame(body=listBox, header=debug)
urwid.MainLoop(frame).run()
```

Reference: [Urwid > Signal functions > connect](http://urwid.org/reference/signals.html?highlight=urwid.signal#urwid.Signals.connect)

[image]

Comment: checkout https://github.com/zulip/zulip-terminal for more high level examples of using urwid.